# golang: Unmarshal dynamic YAML annonation

Tags: go, yaml

I want to dynamically change the annotation of a `struct` and use `yaml.Unmarshal` like below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

type User struct {
    Name string `yaml:"dummy"`
}

func (u *User) UnmarshalYAML(node *yaml.Node) error {
    value := reflect.ValueOf(*u)
    t := value.Type()
    fields := make([]reflect.StructField, 0)

    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        fields = append(fields, t.Field(i))

        if t.Field(i).Name == "Name" {
            fields[i].Tag = `yaml:"name"` // Dynamic annotation
        }
    }

    newType := reflect.StructOf(fields)
    newValue := value.Convert(newType)

    err := node.Decode(newValue.Interface()) // Cause error because it's not pointer
    return err
}

var dat string = `name: abc`

func main() {
    out := User{}
    yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(dat), &out)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", out)
}
```

It causes errors like `panic: reflect: reflect.Value.Set using unaddressable value [recovered]` and I think it's because `node.Decode` is not used with a pointer. So how to create the pointer of the new type?

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/_1UeEwrxafw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here goes the updated demo that works:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

type User struct {
    Name string `yaml:"dummy"`
}

func (u *User) UnmarshalYAML(node *yaml.Node) error {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(*u)
    fields := make([]reflect.StructField, 0)

    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        fields = append(fields, t.Field(i))

        if t.Field(i).Name == "Name" {
            fields[i].Tag = `yaml:"name"` // Dynamic annotation
        }
    }

    newType := reflect.StructOf(fields)
    newValue := reflect.NewAt(newType, unsafe.Pointer(u)).Elem()

    err := node.Decode(newValue.Addr().Interface())
    return err
}

var dat string = `name: abc`

func main() {
    out := User{}
    yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(dat), &out)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", out)
}
```

Two key changes:

1. Replace `newValue.Interface()` with `newValue.Addr().Interface()`. (See this example: https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#example-StructOf)
2. Replace `newValue := value.Convert(newType)` with `newValue := reflect.NewAt(newType, unsafe.Pointer(u)).Elem()`.

   We do this because `value` in `value := reflect.ValueOf(*u)` is unaddressable (You can verify it with `fmt.Printf("%v", value.Addr())`. It panics with message `panic: reflect.Value.Addr of unaddressable value`).